# How to keep your fingernail clippers together?

Tags: gear, survival

Fingernail clippers are super helpful in outdoor situations. This is my number one always in my pocket survival tool.  But they have a tendency to come apart, [there are even videos showing how to put them back together,](https://www.wikihow.com/Fix-Nail-Clippers) all to often when the come apart the little pin gets lost and I need to purchase a replacement, which is fine if I am not miles from civilization when it happens.

How to keep your fingernail clippers together? *(I wanted to say "keep in one piece", but they are one device with 3 snap together pieces)*

Comment: That's quite enough. If you want to discuss the on-/off-topicness of this question further, post a meta question on it.

Comment: @Kevin Can you please bring back the other comments that were not about the on-/off-topicness of this question? It's fine if they come back as a linked chat, as I would have made it a chat in the first place if I could.

Comment: @Aaron there are no comments worth salvaging. Go ahead and ask about alternative uses for nail clippers in chat.

Answer (score 2):

Did some experimenting, and it looks like its only possible for them to come apart when the lever is up, so all you should need to do is **store it in the down configuration** and if you needed the extra security, **keep them that way with a rubber band.**

It takes a little bit of force and coordination to get them apart if you really want to, so rattling around in your pack shouldn't be a problem. We always had a  **pair in the first aid kit** and it was just in a ziplock with the other tweezers and so on.

Comment: Mine manage to swivel open in my pocket frequently, the occurrence of coming apart in my pocket, about 4 times a year.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of alternative nail clipper designs. Some of these look better for carrying, and probably prevent the problem, but they may not work as well in a survival situation.

For a typical pair of clippers, I suggest taping them so the lever cannot swivel and the cutting edge is covered. That said, they also sell (or you can make), keychain/belt loop cases for nail clippers (e.g., https://www.etsy.com/dk-en/listing/504217168/fingernail-clip-keychain-finger-nail).